# How to remove this error message: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'seconds' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to receive a boost as I have been stuck on this issue for quite some time. Thank you very much for your precious time.

**Goal :**

I would like to solve a problem. The problem is this error message in the console:

[image]

**Results:**

I am using firestore and the timestamp looks like this:

Timestamp (seconds = 1620748267, nanoseconds = 746000000)

I know how to display the value I want but cannot remove this error .. I tried to transform the timestamp into a javascript date by looking at the firebase documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) but it just replaces the error .. Every thing I put after the timestamp turns into an error in the console..

**My code :**

```
<small class="text-muted"> {{ dateTime(job) }}</small>
```

My function dateTime :

```
dateTime(job) {
  const createdAt = job.createdAt;
  const d = new Date(createdAt.seconds * 1000);
  const currDate = d.getDate();
  const currMonth = d.getMonth() + 1;
  const currYear = d.getFullYear();
  const dateTime = `${currDate}-${currMonth}-${currYear}`;
  return dateTime;
}
```

So, would you know where the problem is coming from? If you are missing anything, please let me know, thank you!

Comment: Hello, it seems the problem is with your "createdAt" variable, which is undefined when you try to access the "seconds" property on it. I take it "job" is an object? I would look at that object either in the console or the debugger

Comment: Hello @JTInfinite, thank you for your answer. Job is indeed an object ! An object having "createdAt", and in this "createdAt" there is :

Timestamp (seconds = 1620748267, nanoseconds = 746000000)

Comment: createdAt is undefined so this leads me to believe that job does not have createdAt...?

Comment: The error could be arising because you are rendering this component before there is a job

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating your own `Date` object from the Firestore Timestamp, try using the Firestore Timestamp's `toDate` method to create a `Date` instead.

`const d = createdAt.toDate()`

Comment: Hello @Michael Prather, thank you for your answer. This changes my "seconds" error to "toDate"..

Comment: Consistent with some of the other comments and @tony19's suggestion, try logging the value of `job.createdAt` to see if there is a defined value prior to it being converted to a Date.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `job` is initially an empty object and asynchronously updated (after an API call) to include `createdAt`. Your template likely renders that markup unconditionally *before* this update occurs, at which point `job.createdAt` is `undefined`.

A simple fix is to check `job.createdAt` before trying to use it:

```js
dateTime(job) {
  const createdAt = job.createdAt;
  if (!createdAt) return ''

  //...
}
```

Alternatively, you could initialize `job` to `null`, and conditionally render that date markup, assuming `job.createdAt` will exist when `job` is populated:

```html
<template>
  <small class="text-muted" v-if="job"> {{ dateTime(job) }}</small>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      job: null, // asynchronously updated by API call
    }
  }
}
</script>
```